# Bootstrap dropdown menus in navigation bar on click event

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

In my site I use the code below to show dropdown menus of my navigation bar on mouse hover event:

```
$(".nav-item").hover(function () {
    var menu_id = $(this).attr('data-category-id');
    $("#menu_content_" + menu_id).show();
  
    
}, function () {
    var menu_id = $(this).attr('data-category-id');
    $("#menu_content_" + menu_id).hide();
   
});
```

What I want is to do the same but on click event instead of hover. I tried

```
$(".nav-item").click(function () {
```

but didn't work. The dropdown menus are displaying but stay always open. Any idea of what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: What do you mean by "didn't work"?

Comment: I mean that the drop-down menus are displaying but stay always open and they dont hide when you click on different navigation items

Comment: Try and add the relevant HTML to the question or add the full code to a fiddle and share it with us